# Syntactic sugar for "If this parameter is null, automatically return null"

Tags: c#, syntactic-sugar

Is there any case for syntactic sugar that returns null when a specific parameter is null? Does this exist?

```
public DataObj GetMyData(DataSource source?null, User currentUser?null, string path) {
    // Code starts here. source and currentUser are not null.
}
```

or this

```
public DataObj GetMyData(DataSource source!, User currentUser!, string path) {
    // Code starts here. source and currentUser are not null.
}
```

So the above would return null if either the source or currentUser were null without having to execute the method, but it would execute if only the path was null.

```
public DataObj GetMyData(DataSource source, User currentUser, string path) {
    if (source == null || currentUser == null)
    { 
        return null;
    }
    // The rest of your code here
}
```

You could also use ArgumentNullExceptions, but then you are creating additional exception handling work elsewhere especially if null parameters are ok, but you don't get a value from it.

Comment: No, there is nothing like this in C#.

Comment: What would such a method return for a value type?

Comment: Is there a language that actually does this?

Comment: @AlexK. Presumably the syntax simply wouldn't be valid and would result in a compiler error if the return type wasn't nullable.

Comment: @TyCobb It would be pretty easy to write one, or more precisely a language extension that compiled code with this syntax down into another language.  The transformation is simple enough.

Comment: @Servy I get that. Just wondered if one existed which prompted this question about C# possibly having that mechanism. Just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# 6 is proposing a [null propagation operator](http://davefancher.com/2014/08/14/c-6-0-null-propagation-operator/) `?` that will turn:

```
double? minPrice = null;
if (product != null
    && product.PriceBreaks != null
    && product.PriceBreaks[0] != null)
{
  minPrice = product.PriceBreaks[0].Price;
}
```

into:

```
var minPrice = product?.PriceBreaks?[0]?.Price;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no syntactic sugar to return null.

I think the closest thing that exist is operations on nullable values:

```
int? Add(int? l, int? r)
{
    return l + r;  
}
```

Will give you "HasValue = false" if either operand does not have value.

You may also want to read about "Maybe monad" which is very close to what you are looking for - i.e. [Marvels of Monads](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2008/01/11/the-marvels-of-monads.aspx) tries to explain one in C# (nullable values is example on one, but apply only to value types).

Answer (score 0):

If it is something you find yourself doing a few times, it would make sense to put it into a generic method. That method can do the checks and it will use a function that will do the actual operation after checking for the nulls on the arguments.

```
public T OperateIfNotNull<T, V1, V2>(V1 arg1, V2 arg2, string path, Func<V1, V2, string, T> operation) where T : class
{
    if ((arg1 == null) || (arg2 == null) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
        return null;

    return operation(arg1, arg2, path);

}
```